# Firebase : http resources

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I developed a mobile application with firebase in back end and ionic in front end. 
How I can have all my resources Get, Put, Post and Delete in http of my application because. I used the Observable object of firebase in my code.

Please assist on this.

Thanks,

Michael

Answer (score 0):

I used [angularfire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2) to connect to firebase in an ionic 2/3 application.
You can check out these [docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/Auth-with-Ionic3-Angular4.md) to properly use firebase in your ionic application.